# ssh localhost returning intermittent unpredictable behaviour

Tags: linux, ssh

i ran the following command many times.

`ssh -vvv localhost 'echo hello'`

however, it returns unpredictable results.

sometimes it works perfectly well. at times, i receive the following error.

```
2020-08-31 00:30:08  debug(1) pid=10607 Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22 address family IPv4.
2020-08-31 00:30:08  debug(2) pid=10607 HPN: is disable. Not setting SO_RCVBUF.
2020-08-31 00:30:08  debug(2) category(Network)  pid=10607 fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
2020-08-31 00:30:08  debug(1) pid=10607 connect to address 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
2020-08-31 00:30:08  debug(1) pid=10607 ssh_connect: Skipping non-IPV4 address, because addressFamily is configured for IPV4 only.
Failed to connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Any help/explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that "many times" as in "very quickly"? `sshd` will only allow a certain number of connections waiting for authentication (10 by default) and then start immediately rejecting a percentage (30 by default) of new connections.

Comment: actually it might be, because it is a headless account. And everyone else is sudo'ed as the headless account, and then call the ```ssh``` command.

Comment: Why not look at the right logs and find out?  Show potential answers the SSH _server_ logs _as well_, in the question.